# bundle.update() from another bundle fails

Tags: java, service, osgi, bundle

I'm building a simple OSGi demo application to learn about the framework. I want to update an active bundle from within another bundle, or from an application with the OSGi framework embedded in it (as described in [How To Embed OSGi by Neil Bartlett](http://njbartlett.name/2011/03/07/embedding-osgi.html)).

My application is broken into these bundles (I've placed the code at the end of the post for easier reading):

1. com.dc.sszostek.interfaces - contains a single Shape interface with the method draw()
2. com.dc.sszostek.implementations - there are 2 bundles with this SymbolicName, each implementing the Shape interface: println's a Line, the other a Square. Both of their manifest files are the same, the bundles only differ in the implementation.
3. com.dc.sszostek.programs - contains a Painter program; it uses the Shape interface to draw() (I've used the [OSGi Services - Tutorial by Lars Vogel](http://www.vogella.com/articles/OSGiServices/article.html) to write it).
4. com.dc.sszostek.xmpp - contains a Jabber client implemented using the SmackAPI, waiting for a file transfer and trying to update the com.dc.sszostek.implementations bundle when it receives a file.

My problem is that when I send different implementations to my application, the files get written, but then bundle doesn't get updated.

`bundle.update()` gets called, it doesn't throw an exception, but my program keeps drawing a Line (or a Square, depending which bundle I've put in first). When I update the bundle from the OSGi console, it gets replaced correctly, and my demo starts drawing a different shape.

Can anyone tell me where is the mistake I am making, or point me to a working example?

Thank you in advance.

---

com.dc.sszostek.interfaces

MANIFEST.MF

```
    Manifest-Version: 1.0
    Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
    Bundle-Name: Provider
    Bundle-SymbolicName: com.dc.sszostek.interfaces
    Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
    Export-Package: com.dc.sszostek.interfaces
```

Shape.java

```
    package com.dc.sszostek.interfaces;

    public interface Shape {
        void draw();
    }
```

---

com.dc.sszostek.implementations

MANIFEST.MF

```
    Manifest-Version: 1.0
    Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
    Bundle-Name: Impl
    Bundle-SymbolicName: com.dc.sszostek.implementations
    Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
    Bundle-Activator: com.dc.sszostek.implementations.Activator
    Export-Package: com.dc.sszostek.implementations
    Import-Package: org.osgi.framework, com.dc.sszostek.interfaces
```

Activator.java

```
    package com.dc.sszostek.implementations;

    import org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator;
    import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;
    import com.dc.sszostek.interfaces.Shape;

    public class Activator implements BundleActivator {

        public void start(BundleContext ctx) throws Exception {
            ctx.registerService(Shape.class.getName(), new Line(), null);
        }

        public void stop(BundleContext ctx) throws Exception {}
    }
```

Line.java

```
    package com.dc.sszostek.implementations;

    import com.dc.sszostek.interfaces.Shape;

    public class Line implements Shape {
        public void draw() {
            System.out.println("*********");
        }
    }
```

---

com.dc.sszostek.programs

MANIFEST.MF

```
    Manifest-Version: 1.0
    Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
    Bundle-Name: Prog
    Bundle-SymbolicName: com.dc.sszostek.programs
    Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
    Bundle-Activator: com.dc.sszostek.programs.Activator
    Export-Package: com.dc.sszostek.programs
    Import-Package: org.osgi.framework, com.dc.sszostek.interfaces
```

Activator.java

```
    package com.dc.sszostek.programs;

    import org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator;
    import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;
    import org.osgi.framework.ServiceReference;
    import com.dc.sszostek.interfaces.Shape;

    public class Activator implements BundleActivator {
        private MyThread thread;

        public void start(BundleContext ctx) throws Exception {
            ServiceReference ref = getServiceReference(ctx);
            thread = new MyThread((Shape)ctx.getService(ref));
            thread.start();
        }

        public void stop(BundleContext ctx) throws Exception {
            ServiceReference ref = getServiceReference(ctx);
            ctx.ungetService(ref);
            thread.stopThread();
        }

        private ServiceReference getServiceReference(BundleContext ctx) {
            ServiceReference ref = ctx.getServiceReference(Shape.class.getName());
            return ref;
        }

        public static class MyThread extends Thread {
            private volatile boolean active = true;
            private final Shape service;

            public MyThread(Shape service) {
                this.service = service;
            }

            public void run() {
                while (active) {
                    service.draw();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("Thread interrupted: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }

            public void stopThread() {
                active = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

---

com.dc.sszostek.programs

MANIFEST.MF

```
    Manifest-Version: 1.0
    Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
    Bundle-Name: FileReceiver
    Bundle-SymbolicName: com.dc.sszostek.xmpp
    Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
    Bundle-Activator: com.dc.sszostek.xmpp.Activator
    Bundle-ClassPath: ., lib/smack-3.2.1.jar, lib/smackx-3.2.1.jar
    Import-Package: org.osgi.framework, javax.net, javax.security.auth.callback, javax.net.ssl, javax.security.sasl,
        javax.naming.directory, javax.naming
```

Activator.java

```
    package com.dc.sszostek.xmpp;

    import org.jivesoftware.smack.*;
    import org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.*;
    import org.osgi.framework.Bundle;
    import org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator;
    import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;
    import org.osgi.framework.BundleException;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;

    public class Activator implements BundleActivator {
        private Connection connection;

        public void start(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
            final BundleContext ctx = bundleContext;

            try {
                connection = new XMPPConnection("JABBER_SERVER");
                connection.connect();
                connection.login("USER", "PASS");

                final FileTransferManager manager = new FileTransferManager(connection);
                FileTransferNegotiator.getInstanceFor(connection);
                FileTransferNegotiator.setServiceEnabled(connection, true);

                manager.addFileTransferListener(new FileTransferListener() {
                    public void fileTransferRequest(FileTransferRequest request) {
                        IncomingFileTransfer transfer = request.accept();

                        File file = new File("D:\\bundles\\" + transfer.getFileName());

                        try {
                            file.createNewFile();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                        }

                        try {
                            transfer.recieveFile(file);
                        } catch (XMPPException e) {
                            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                        }

                        Bundle bundle = ctx.getBundle(2); //com.dc.sszostek.implementations is bundle number 2
                        try {
                            bundle.update();
                        } catch (BundleException e) {
                            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        public void stop(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't start with activators in OSGi, activators are unfortunate remains from past times. Activators are singletons (which is really bad!) and they force you to handle your dependencies yourself. Though they are sometimes useful in very special cases because they do not depend on other bundles. However, virtually all cases Declarative Services is the way to go.

Lots of people want to learn OSGi from the bottom but using activators is like learning how to drive on today's roads in Fred Flintstone's car. Bound to get yourself hurt.

You're actually showing all the pitfalls that happen to you when you use activators. Services are not guaranteed to be present when you start your activator. You also show a really bad idea, opening connections to an external service in your activator. Activators start/stop method must be very quick to kick off all bundles quickly.

Anyway, except for Neil's suggestion. You realize update() is using the old url you gave it? Did you change the file that URL pointed to? You probably want to use the update(InputStream) method to ensure the bundle is really updated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've used `update(InputStream)` and it was a part of the solution. Like Neil Bartlett suggested, I've also modified the thread.

Also thank you for the comments. This was an excercise for me, the next step wil be improving the quality of the solution. I've got myself a copy of "OSGi in action", this will hopefully help (I'd be also gratefull if you could recommend other books worth reading?).

Comment: What you should read is of course my book :-) Unfortunately it is not written since it is hard to justify writing it :-(

Answer (score 0):

Do you expect the implementation of the service to change while `MyThread` is running? Because it looks like you only obtain the service once, before starting the thread, and reuse it forever. Under these conditions it's impossible for the implementation to change, at least until you kill and restart the thread.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've changed my solution, passing the `BundleContext` to the thread and in it getting the `ServiceReference` and finally my service each time before using it (this of course lead sometimes to exceptions when my service was updating, so the ServiceReference was then null). I've also switched to update(InputStream), as Peter Kriens suggested, and the whole solution worked. (Also apologies for not marking your answer also as the accepted answer, the site won't let me mark 2 answers as accepted). What's left for me is to improve the solution and learn more.

Comment: No problem about accepting Peter's answer. He's a behind in reputation points so need a bit of a leg up ;-)